# Anchor tag to open bootstrap modal and pass a parameter based on dropdown value in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something here which got me stucked up for quite some time.

I have a Php form which has an anchor tag and a dropdown. I managed to open a modal using the anchor tag but how do I pass the value of the dropdown to that modal.

Here's the anchor tag and dropdown script

```
<label id="labelfordropdown"><strong>Filter By Month:</strong></label>
<select name="datestart" id="datestart" class="form-control" style="width:500px;">
    <option value="">--Select Month--</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

Then the anchor tag

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegister" data-id=""> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span> Details</a>
```

And heres the modal

```
<div id="modalRegister" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align-last: center">Register</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I pass the data let's say December to modal using that anchor tag. So I can create an ajax for that modal.

Thanks.

Comment: where exactly you want to put the value in your modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will get the value of you dropdown when the modal is already visible.

```js
$('#modalRegister').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  var datestart = $('#datestart').val(); // value  of your dropdown
  // it is now up to you on what you do on the value of your dropdown here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your modal div make a hidden input like:

...

```
<input type="hidden" id="myVal" value="" />
```

and on click of anchor that opens the modal pass the value to this hidden input like:

```
$('#modalRegister').click(function(){
    $('#myVal').val('any value');
});
```